# notifyDatasetChanged ListView with Android 7 error loop

Tags: android, listview

I have a `ListView` with an `EditText` inside having an input type of numeric. When I use `notifyDatasetChanged()` in the focus event of the `EditText` I get an error.

is notifydatasetchanged()->focus->notifyDatasetChanged()->focus......
That error happens with android 7 or higher.

**getView()**

```
final ArrayAdapterListProduct.ViewHolder holder = new ArrayAdapterListProduct.ViewHolder();
    holder.caption = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.changegift_listview_item_number);
    if (promotionItem.getNumber_choose() != 0) {
        holder.caption.setText(promotionItem.getNumber_choose() + "");
    }
    holder.caption.setId(position);

    holder.caption.addTextChangedListener(new MyTextWatcher(holder.caption));
    int temp_cout_product = 0;
    if (promotionItem.getSoluongtonkho() > promotionItem.getPromotion_canget()) {
        temp_cout_product = promotionItem.getPromotion_canget();
    } else {
        temp_cout_product = promotionItem.getSoluongtonkho();
    }

    holder.caption.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
            if (!b) {
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    });

    holder.caption.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilterMinMax(0, temp_cout_product)});
    return view;
```

So I can't input numberic into editext

Comment: Can you please add the exception log.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is you are setting the `OnFocusChangeListener` inside the `getView()` method and inside that you are calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` when the view does not have focus. What actually happens with this code is your `ListView` is created with the initial call to `notifyDataSetChanged()` and is filled with views that **do not have focus**. This means that every time `getView()` is called and you set the `OnFocusChangeListener` it's going to recall `notifyDataSetChanged()` resulting in an infinite loop.

Without seeing more of your code or understanding why you are calling `notifiyDataSetChanged()` inside a focus listener it's hard to help.

Comment: when i unfocus edittext(input type number) in item listview i need update text view with values in editext and refresh listview for display new values

Comment: With android less than 7.0 then don't have that issue :(